# wp10:TextBox with flyout not firing lost focus on every got focus

Tags: windows-phone, uwp, windows-10-universal, windows-10-mobile

Existing OS version :WinowsPhone 8.1.
Device: Nokia Lumia 925.

**XAML code:**

```
<TextBox
    x:Name="txtDtpEnd0"
    Grid.Row="2"
    Grid.Column="0"
    Width="130"
    Height="30"
    Margin="22,0,0,0"
    HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
    VerticalAlignment="Top"
    BorderBrush="Gray"
    BorderThickness="0.5"
    FontFamily="Segoe UI"
    FontSize="15"
    Foreground="Black"
    GotFocus="DeclarativeInlineButton_GotFocus">
    <FlyoutBase.AttachedFlyout>
        <DatePickerFlyout
            x:Name="DtpEnd0"
            Title="Select a date"
            Closed="datePicker_Closed"
            DatePicked="datePicker0_DatePicked" />
    </FlyoutBase.AttachedFlyout>
</TextBox>
```

**Code in c# :**

```
private void DeclarativeInlineButton_GotFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Windows.UI.ViewManagement.InputPane.GetForCurrentView().TryHide();
            TextBox TB = (TextBox)sender;
            FlyoutBase.ShowAttachedFlyout(TB);
            //Windows.UI.ViewManagement.InputPane.GetForCurrentView().TryShow();
        }
```

**Functionality in WP8.1**
On focusing of this text box datepicker flyout appear an user can select a date from date picker.

**Result In WP8.1** 
User able to select date and functionality work as expected.

**Result In WP10** 
On focus of textbox softkeyboard appear but sometimes datepicker also appear.

**easy Case for soft keyboard :** when i hold back button for long and resume to app this and try to focus textbox soft keyboard start appearing. to remove softkeyboard i need to close app and relaunch it.

**Conclusion:**

But sometimes softkeyboard start appearing without back button hold.

Comment: I tested your code but I did not reproduce your issue. This is my [demo](https://github.com/ZhuMingHao/PlayerTest.git). Could you tell me what kind of effect do you want to achieve?

Comment: let me check with demo. you can try with switching apps and then try to focus text box it will not open DatePickerFlyout .

Comment: ok what should i do to get datepicker flyout after app resume.

Comment: One more thing this demo app is min-target in w10 but for my app min app target is w8.1.

Answer (score 0):

Finally after applying latest windows 10 update(10.0.14393.693) this problem resolved without making any changes in app.